# Open3270 C# Screen size

Tags: c#, mainframe

I'm using [Open3270](https://github.com/Open3270/Open3270) on C# to control a mainframe system that we use in the company I work at.

The problem is that, when we open the mainframe window by hand, it's a 24 line, 80 column grid of characters, but the Open3270 emulator uses a 24 line, 72 column grid version of the same window.

I'm making an automation tool using Open3270 to let user navigate the mainframe programmaticaly and some people are having problems using it when they need to access elements on the screen that are at positions, say, 24-75. It's ok on the manual window but, on the emulator, the user would have to change pages as the page is shorter and can't hold as many elements.

Is there a way to make the emulator window be the same size as the mainframe window? Or is there a better tool to use for automation on the mainframe?

Some code for connecting with the mainframe:

```
    emulator = new TNEmulator();
    emulator.Debug = false;
    emulator.Config.TermType = "IBM-3278-2-E";
    emulator.Config.FastScreenMode = true;
    emulator.Connect("[IP]", [PORT], null);
    emulator.Refresh(true, 20000);
```

Comment: What exactly does "by hand" mean in this context?

Comment: The library you are using is open source on Github.  You can track down where it is setting the screen width/height, and even modify it to better suit your needs.

Comment: Sorry if it was unclear. By "by hand" I mean manually opening the mainframe window and navigating through it, as opposed to navigating programmaticaly using Open3270

Answer (score 0):

Terminal type = screen resolution (Screen size):
Eg,
IBM-3477-FC : 27x132 color display
IBM-3179-2 : 24x80 color display

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).